# bitcode_strip failed on Xcode application export

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My Xcode application builds and runs fine on all targets.  But, export fails when I attempt to distribute a build with via the 'Save for Development Deployment' or 'Save for Enterprise Deployment' option from Xcode Organizer.  I uncheck 'Rebuild with bitcode' on the Summary page.  Then, after clicking 'Next' I get a ***bitcode_strip failed*** error.

Does anyone know why we would get a bitcode_strip failure at application export?  Do you know if there is any way to suppress or work around this error?

I have STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES set to 'NO' for all my frameworks, projects and targets.  I also have Enable Bitcode set to 'NO' for all of the above.

Xcode 7.2.1

Answer (score 2):

To work around this issue, I used a command line script to export the IPA instead of the Xcode Organizer.

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa \
    -archivePath "/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp.xcarchive" \
    -exportPath "/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp.ipa" \
    -exportProvisioningProfile "myappprofile"
```